# Do Oracle materialized view records get timestamp automatically?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, materialized-views

Do Oracle materialized view records get timestamp automatically?

Comment: what do you mean with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle materialized view records do not get a timestamp automatically. However, a System Change Number (SCN) can be included with each record by adding "ORA_ROWSCN AS SCN" to the select statement. System Change Numbers (SCN) provide a row version number and are updated when the row is updated.

Answer (score 3):

The date of the last refresh for a materialized view is held in ALL_MVIEWS.LAST_REFRESH_DATE (or USER_MVIEWS.LAST_REFRESH_DATE).